# What are the security risks of a WiFi-to-Ethernet adapter for connecting to a Blu-ray player?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security

I recently bought a Blu-ray player that supports streaming but does not have built-in WiFi. I want to buy a device that accepts WiFi wirelessly and sends output to an Ethernet cable that can attach to the Blu-ray player. There are a number of such devices that are sold on Amazon. My question is: What could such a device do with the information it intercepts? For instance, could it decrypt information from the network (such as credit card transactions performed on a laptop on the network) and send it to a remote server in China?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I edited the question.

Comment: This question is not about computers and so is off topic. But to answer your question: if the traffic is not encrypted, such a device as you describe would have full access to and full control of the data it passes along. If the data is encrypted securely and correctly, then it would not. There is also a lot of middle ground.